# How to get Flex components to fill available space using Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, viewstack, vbox

I was laying out my Flex components using mxml and had them working correctly.  But then I wanted to switch them over to Actionscript because I wanted them to extend a base component that provides default functionality.

I've go the code working except that my components that used to fill the entire space using width="100%" and height="100%" appear to display just using the default sizes.  Do you know How I can get them to take up the entire space again?

Here is a test component I am playing with that exhibits the problem.

Main.mxml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:bbq="components.*"
    backgroundGradientColors="[#000000, #3333dd]"
    minWidth="480" minHeight="320"
    layout="vertical" verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center"
    paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="30" paddingBottom="0"
    width="100%" height="100%" >`

```
<mx:VBox backgroundColor="0xcccc66">
    <mx:ViewStack id="mainViewStack" width="100%" height="100%" color="0x323232">
        <bbq:TestComp id="testComp" height="100%" width="100%" />
        <bbq:ResultsBox />
    </mx:ViewStack>
</mx:VBox>
```

TestComp.as

`package components {`

`import mx.containers.VBox;`

`import mx.containers.Panel;`

`import flash.events.*;`

```
public class TestComp extends VBox {
    private var p:Panel;

    function TestComp(){
        super();
        percentHeight = 100;
        percentWidth = 100;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();
        p = new Panel();
        p.percentHeight = 100;
        p.percentWidth = 100;
        p.title = "Test Comp";
        addChild(p);
    }       
}
```

`}`

Comment: You can do inheritance in MXML, right?

Comment: This seems to be okay - can you post the corresponding mxml? Are you sure about the height/width of the TestComp - were you using fixed values in mxml?

Comment: I added the code above that wraps the test component.

Answer (score 0):

Add inherited method calls; calls to super() methods;

```
import mx.containers.VBox;
import mx.containers.Panel;
import flash.events.*;

public class TestComp extends VBox {
    private var p:Panel;

    function TestComp(){
        super(); // add this line

        percentHeight = 100;
        percentWidth = 100;
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren(); // add this line

        p = new Panel();
        p.percentHeight = 100;
        p.percentWidth = 100;
        p.title = "Test Comp";
        addChild(p);
    }       
}
```

In you mxml:

```
<local:TestComp width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Comment: I added these supers but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might know what it is.  I think I explicitly set the width and height of one of the other components in the viewstack, and I think that affected the viewstack itself so that all of the other components that were added to it also go those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
resizeToContent=true
```